# SwiftUI onAppear is called 2 times while if else construction is used to show two ContentViews

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to implement the structure where I have two different views with if else.

Minimal reproducable example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var shouldShowContentView1 = true

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if shouldShowContentView1 {
                NavigationView {
                    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                        ContentView1(shouldShowView: $shouldShowContentView1)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                NavigationView {
                    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                        ContentView3()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView1: View {

    @Binding private var shouldShowView: Bool
    @State private var shouldShowContent2: Bool = false

    init(shouldShowView: Binding<Bool>) {
        _shouldShowView = shouldShowView
    }

    var body: some View {

        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2(shouldShowView: $shouldShowView), isActive: $shouldShowContent2) {}

        Button(action: {
            shouldShowContent2 = true
        }) {
            Text("Skip1")
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("ContentView1 Appeared")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {

    @Binding private var shouldShowView: Bool

    init(shouldShowView: Binding<Bool>) {
        _shouldShowView = shouldShowView
    }

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {
            shouldShowView = false
        }) {
            Text("Skip2")
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("ContentView2 Appeared")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!3")
            .padding()
            .onAppear {
                print("ContentView3 Appeared")
            }
    }
}
```

I am using this switch logic with two `NavigationView` because of internal need, so I am trying to switch between the first flow and the second flow using the `@State shouldShowContentView1`

When I press on `Skip2` I correctly see ContentView3, but for some reason `onAppear` is called again on  `ContentView1` and `ContentView2`.

```
ContentView1 Appeared
ContentView2 Appeared
ContentView1 Appeared
ContentView3 Appeared
ContentView2 Appeared
```

Can't figure out why is this happening and how to fix it.

Comment: It is known "side-effect" of `NavigationView`, but it has been already deprecated since SwiftUI 4, so submitting feedback worthless... either ignore it or workaround with some explicit check, but I would recommend to avoid dependency on that.